# Server-to-Android feedback: Best practice?

Tags: android

In our app we have a quite a lot of settings, some only applicable to the server (like privacy settings) and others mostly to the app (like location or text-to-speech settings).

We are now moving these settings from native (where most will report back to the server) to webviews. That means loading a settings webpage in a webview on the app thus acting (changing settings) directly on the server.

In case a webview setting should effect the app itself, the server will need to send feedback to the app on the setting change. In this case I could create a receiver to catch a JSON sent back from the server, or use some kind of a silent push notification.

It there a better strait forward way of sending a feedback like that?

Comment: What you want a config file that change the behavior of your application. If the changes are not severe then you can hit for your config file which is stored on your server everytime on splash screen. Because constantly listening for a event to occur on a server is not a good practice in android.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest implementing a push notification based update. The workflow would be as follows:-

1. Generate a firebase token on the android device and save the token against the current logged in account on the server.

2.When the settings are modified, let the server call the firebase push notification API indicating that a settings change has occurred.

3.In the callback when the push notification is received, make a request to the server asking for the new set of settings (JSON or whatever) and store it offline in the Shared Preferences or Storage.

IMPORTANT: Make sure your push notification callback is called even when the app is closed. (Data Message type of push notification)